# issue with parsing data from txt file using python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, geojson

I am trying to take in the following data set but I keep getting errors with the parsing. I'm trying to create a geoJSON file that looks like this

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "description": "PlaceBC",
                "name": "A"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        103.9364834,
                        1.3218368
                    ],
                    [
                        103.9364744,
                        1.3218821
                    ],
                    [
                        103.9367017,
                        1.3219285
                    ],
                    [
                        103.9364707,
                        1.321643
                    ],
                    [
                        103.9363887,
                        1.3216271
                    ],
                    [
                        103.9344606,
                        1.3235089
                    ],
                    [
                        103.9355026,
                        1.3237205
                    ],
                    [
                        103.934106,
                        1.3217046
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
```

So I'm obtaining the data from a txt file but here I'm using a sample set for quick testing.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import io

col = ['lat','long','name','description']
data = '''lat=1.3218368,long=103.9364834,107244,Place BC
lat=1.3218821,long=103.9364744,107243,Place BC
lat=1.3219285,long=103.9367017,107242,Place BC
lat=1.321643,long=103.9364707,107241,Place BC
lat=1.3216271,long=103.9363887,107240,Place BC
lat=1.3235089,long=103.9344606,107148,Place BC
lat=1.3237205,long=103.9355026,107115,Place BC
lat=1.3217046,long=103.934106,107065,Place BC
lat=1.3203204,long=103.9366324,107053,Place BC
lat=1.3206557,long=103.9373536,107052,Place BC
lat=1.3206271,long=103.9374192,107051,Place BC
lat=1.3205511,long=103.9371742,107050,Place BC
lat=1.3206044,long=103.9375056,107049,Place BC
lat=1.3207561,long=103.9371863,107048,Place BC
lat=1.3204307,long=103.9368537,107047,Place BC
lat=1.3204877,long=103.9368389,107046,Place BC
lat=1.3205465,long=103.9368269,107045,Place BC
lat=1.320612,long=103.9368246,107044,Place BC'''

#load csv as dataframe (replace io.StringIO(data) with the csv filename), use converters to clean up lat and long columns upon loading
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), names=col, sep=',', engine='python', converters={'lat': lambda x: float(x.split('=')[1]), 'long': lambda x: float(x.split('=')[1])})
#input the data from the text file
    #df = pd.read_csv("latlong.txt", names=col, sep=',', engine='python', converters={'lat': lambda x: float(x.split('=')[1]), 'long': lambda x: float(x.split('=')[1])})
    
    
    #load dataframe as geodataframe
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.long, df.lat))
    #groupby on name and description, while converting the grouped geometries to a LineString
    gdf = gdf.groupby(['name', 'description'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist())).reset_index()
    
    gdf.to_json()
```

This is the errors that I am getting,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14056/627086265.py in <module>
     32 gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.long, df.lat))
     33 #groupby on name and description, while converting the grouped geometries to a LineString
---> 34 gdf = gdf.groupby(['name', 'description'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist())).reset_index()
     35 
     36 gdf.to_json()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    221     )
    222     def apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
--> 223         return super().apply(func, *args, **kwargs)
    224 
    225     @doc(_agg_template, examples=_agg_examples_doc, klass="Series")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1273         with option_context("mode.chained_assignment", None):
   1274             try:
-> 1275                 result = self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
   1276             except TypeError:
   1277                 # gh-20949

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f, data)
   1307             data after applying f
   1308         """
-> 1309         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, data, self.axis)
   1310 
   1311         return self._wrap_applied_output(

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in apply(self, f, data, axis)
    839             # group might be modified
    840             group_axes = group.axes
--> 841             res = f(group)
    842             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes, axis):
    843                 mutated = True

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14056/627086265.py in <lambda>(x)
     32 gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.long, df.lat))
     33 #groupby on name and description, while converting the grouped geometries to a LineString
---> 34 gdf = gdf.groupby(['name', 'description'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist())).reset_index()
     35 
     36 gdf.to_json()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py in __init__(self, coordinates)
     46         BaseGeometry.__init__(self)
     47         if coordinates is not None:
---> 48             self._set_coords(coordinates)
     49 
     50     @property

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py in _set_coords(self, coordinates)
     95     def _set_coords(self, coordinates):
     96         self.empty()
---> 97         ret = geos_linestring_from_py(coordinates)
     98         if ret is not None:
     99             self._geom, self._ndim = ret

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py()

ValueError: LineStrings must have at least 2 coordinate tuples
```

I'm not sure what's causing the error while I'm parsing the data. Please help :(

Could someone tell me what's the mistake here? Thank you!!!

EDIT:

I have changed 1 line of my groupby to be this

```
gdf.groupby(['name', 'description'])['geometry'] \
             .apply(lambda p: LineString(zip(p.x, p.y)) if len(p) > 1 else p[0])
```

Error I have right now is as follows:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7924/1479654197.py in <module>
     34 #groupby on name and description, while converting the grouped geometries to a LineString
     35 #gdf = gdf.groupby(['description'])['geometry'].apply(lambda p: LineString(zip(p.x, p.y)) if len(p) > 1 else p[0])
---> 36 gdf.groupby(['name', 'description'])['geometry'] \
     37              .apply(lambda p: LineString(zip(p.x, p.y)) if len(p) > 1 else p[0])
     38 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    221     )
    222     def apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
--> 223         return super().apply(func, *args, **kwargs)
    224 
    225     @doc(_agg_template, examples=_agg_examples_doc, klass="Series")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1273         with option_context("mode.chained_assignment", None):
   1274             try:
-> 1275                 result = self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
   1276             except TypeError:
   1277                 # gh-20949

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f, data)
   1307             data after applying f
   1308         """
-> 1309         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, data, self.axis)
   1310 
   1311         return self._wrap_applied_output(

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in apply(self, f, data, axis)
    839             # group might be modified
    840             group_axes = group.axes
--> 841             res = f(group)
    842             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes, axis):
    843                 mutated = True

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7924/1479654197.py in <lambda>(p)
     35 #gdf = gdf.groupby(['description'])['geometry'].apply(lambda p: LineString(zip(p.x, p.y)) if len(p) > 1 else p[0])
     36 gdf.groupby(['name', 'description'])['geometry'] \
---> 37              .apply(lambda p: LineString(zip(p.x, p.y)) if len(p) > 1 else p[0])
     38 
     39 jsonLoad = gdf.to_json()

~\.conda\envs\geojsongen\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    606 
    607     def __getitem__(self, key):
--> 608         return self._wrapped_pandas_method("__getitem__", key)
    609 
    610     @doc(pd.Series)

~\.conda\envs\geojsongen\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py in _wrapped_pandas_method(self, mtd, *args, **kwargs)
    599     def _wrapped_pandas_method(self, mtd, *args, **kwargs):
    600         """Wrap a generic pandas method to ensure it returns a GeoSeries"""
--> 601         val = getattr(super(), mtd)(*args, **kwargs)
    602         if type(val) == Series:
    603             val.__class__ = GeoSeries

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    940 
    941         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 942             return self._get_value(key)
    943 
    944         if is_hashable(key):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1049 
   1050         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1051         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1052         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
   1053 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: In each group ('name', 'description'), there is only one `Point` so it's not enough to create a `LineString`. If you only group by description, it's possible to create a `LineString`

Answer (score 1):

In each group ('name', 'description'), there is only one `Point` so it's not enough to create a `LineString`. If you only group by `description` column, it's possible to create a `LineString`

```
out = gdf.groupby('description')['geometry'].apply(LineString)
print(out)

# Output:
description
Place BC    LINESTRING (103.93648 1.32184, 103.93647 1.321...
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

out.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: LineString]

**Update**

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

# Load your data as previously
# df = read_csv(...)

# Set index to be easier
df = df.set_index(['name', 'description'])

# Partition your data into 2 parts for LineString and Point
mask = df.index.value_counts().gt(1)  # True is a LineString

# Create LineString
ls = df.loc[mask, ['lat', 'long']] \
       .groupby(level=df.index.names) \
       .apply(lambda p: LineString(zip(p['long'], p['lat'])))

# Create Point
pt = df.loc[~mask, ['lat', 'long']] \
       .apply(lambda p: Point(p['long'], p['lat']), axis=1)

# Merge all in GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=pd.concat([ls, pt])).reset_index()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! would it not be possible to have 2 groupings? for name and description? because that is what I wanted to achieve :)

Comment: Yes you can. However, you need at least 2 points to create a LineString. If you have some group with only one point, you have to excluded before to avoid to raise exception. What I don't understand, it's why in your geojson, the name is A and in your sample, names are a sequence of à consecutive numbers?

Comment: previously, the 3rd value was a generic 'A' at first but I replaced it with the numbers and it caused these errors to popped up.
how do I account for those that are just 1 point? sorry I am not very familiar with this part of python yet.

Comment: thanks! not sure if it's a typo but there's an additional '\' in the code and it still throws a few errors wrt to the apply() part. If i change it to not have the 'name'  then it seems like it is okay but not really the output I wanted :) 
  `gdf.groupby(['description'])['geometry'].apply(lambda p: LineString(zip(p.x, p.y)) if len(p) > 1 else p[0])`

Comment: The '\' is to allow one statement on multiple lines and avoid horizontal scrollbar on stackoverflow. What is the error message when you group by ['name', 'description']?

Comment: Oh I see! I have added the newest errors to the original post, thank you!

Comment: Eventually try to replace `p[0]` by `Point(p.x, p.y)`. Does it possible for you to share your dataframe?

Comment: I updated my answer. It should be more robust. I hope :). However in your data, there is still no group

Comment: Thanks :) I think this line couldnt compile on my end `gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=pd.concat([ls, pt])).reset_index()` am I missing a dependency? the error says `ValueError: Must pass array with one dimension only.` :)